# how to plot histogram and time series in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have two different pandas dataframes from which I obtained the following graphs:

```
ar_month_mean.plot(figsize=(15,5))
```

[image]

```
hist_month.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15,5))
```

[image]

I'd like to combine them to obtain something similar to this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass an `ax` to the plotting methods, to have multiple plots in the same `ax`. Otherwise, each new plot will be in a new axis:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
ax = plt.gca()
ar_month_mean.plot(ax=ax, figsize=(15,5))
hist_month.plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', figsize=(15,5))
```

If you post the actually data, I will upload the resulting figure.